# Java: Why does this code work? For loop, if/else statement

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeirdoBinary
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

  String validateBinary;

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a binary number > " );
  validateBinary = scan.nextLine();

  for (int i = 0; i <= validateBinary.length() - 1; i++)
  {

    if (validateBinary.length() >= 8)
      {
      System.out.println("Rejected.");
      break;
        }
       char binary = validateBinary.charAt(i);
        if (binary != '1' && binary != '0')
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid number.");
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            if(i == validateBinary.length() - 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Accepted. " );
                break;

            }
        }
    }
 }
}
```

The code is designed to detected whether the number is binary or not. If the number is binary, it is designed to reject the number if it contains more that 2 one's, and accept it otherwise. What does >= 8 have anything to do with the number of of 1's in the input? How does validatedBinary() - 1 test for the program to only have <= 2 ones?

I am particularly curious about how the for loop works within this program in general.

After running this code, it only asks for input one, and then ends. How do you make it reiterate?

Comment: It doesn't. `if (validateBinary.length() >= 8)` rejects all inputs that are larger than 8 letters, but there's no reason for it to be in the loop. The `if(i == validateBinary.length() - 1)` doesn't test for the number of ones; it just manually breaks the loop, because the for loop condition is wrong. This doesn't do any rejection of numbers where there are more than two `1`s.

Comment: Example showing the acceptance of "011110": https://ideone.com/ln7iLO

Comment: Thank you! I knew it was weird, but it seems to work on the surface. What different methods could be used to get this to work correctly?

Comment: The acceptance of "011110" is correct (is a valid binary). It does reject numbers where there are more than two `1`s see [link](https://ideone.com/qCoVNe) for "011112".

Comment: @Decly It rejects "011112" because 1 and 0 are the only acceptable characters. It does not reject it because there has been more than two `1`s.

Comment: That being said, as you point out, 1111 is no less valid than 0011. @CoderChic is there a reason you are checking that it only has a maximum of 2 ones

Answer (score 2):

The program as you post it prints "Accepted. " for any valid binary number, prints "Invalid number. " for any string that contains a character not equals to '1' or '0' and only rejects the strings with more than 7 characters (`validateBinary.length() >= 8`). The `i == validateBinary.length() - 1` part checks if the index of the for have reached the last character.
The for loop makes i go from 0 to the lenght of the input string - 1, and uses it to get the characters in that position, so iterates character by character the input string.

This modified version of the program address your requirements:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeirdoBinary {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    String validateBinary = "  ";

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(validateBinary.length() > 0) {
      System.out.print("Enter a binary number or enter to finish > " );
      validateBinary = scan.nextLine();
      int ones = 0;

      for (int i = 0; i <= validateBinary.length() - 1; i++) {    

        // Checks that the string is not more than 7 characters long
        if (validateBinary.length() >= 8) {
          System.out.println("Rejected.");
          break;
        }

        // Gets the character at the i position
        char binary = validateBinary.charAt(i);

        // Counts the '1' characters
        if (binary == '1')
          ones++;

        // Verifies that has not more than 2 '1's
        if(ones > 2) {
          System.out.println("Rejected.");
          break;
        }

        // Verifies that only contains '1' or '0'
        if (binary != '1' && binary != '0') {
          System.out.println("Invalid number.");
          break;
        } else {
          // If i reach the end of the string the number is ok
          if(i == validateBinary.length() - 1) {
            System.out.println("Accepted. " );
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it still doesn't work. It accepts 1111 and as Colonel Thirty Two said... well, he's correct. Do you have any ideas as to how it could be fixed?

Comment: Well, 1111 IS a binary number as far as I know (represents the decimal 15).

Comment: @Decly Read the second sentence of the question. _" If the number is binary, it is designed to reject the number if it contains more that 2 one's"_

Comment: @Decly , I understand that. It cannot be a binary number with more that 2 ones. For instance, 10000001 should work as it only has two ones, 1100101, however, should not work.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo You are right I've edited the answer, I missed the weird part of the requirement.

Comment: @CoderChic his edit addresses your question properly, except as far as making it repeat. To do that, you can surround the code with a do while loop or a while loop. (`while` loop runs if a certain condition is met until the point when this is no longer the case or `break`, `do while` runs at least once and keeps going until the `while` condition is no longer met or `break`). @Decly I'm a bit tired and don't feel like writing an answer to address this single point. Assuming you can just throw this in your answer so they can see what the code looks like?

Comment: @Monkeygrinder I modified the code as you suggested. Last nigth I've learned that Stackoverflow must not be used to try to fix imsomnia.

Answer (score 1):

try this version of your code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeirdoBinary {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String validateBinary;
    int i, countOne;
    boolean insertAnotherValue = true;
    char binary;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (insertAnotherValue == true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a binary number > " );
        validateBinary = scan.nextLine();

        //this if is not needed, you could remove it, 
        //its just here to check if the not more than 8 bits long

        //if (validateBinary.length() >= 8) {
        //  System.out.println("Rejected.");
        //} 
        //else {
        countOne = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < validateBinary.length() ; i++) {    
            binary = validateBinary.charAt(i);
            if (binary == '1') {
                countOne++;
            } 
            if ((binary != '1' && binary != '0') || countOne > 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
        //}

        if(i == validateBinary.length()) {
            System.out.println("Accepted. ");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Rejected. ");
        }

        System.out.println("\ninsert another value? (y/n)");
        if (scan.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y") ) {
            insertAnotherValue = true;
        } else {
            insertAnotherValue = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

i believe this fulfills your requirement now.

Comment: There are a couple requirements in the original question that this code doesn't address. Firstly, the binary number must contain no more than two `1`'s. Second, there should be a way to repeat (i.e. enter another number).

Comment: Also, `||` is or, which would always result in true here: if binary = 1, then binary != 0... if binary = 0, then binary != 1... if binary != 0 and binary !=1, then binary != 0 or 1. You meant `&&`.

Comment: I like that you brought the length check outside of the for loop (no need to do it more than once when it's not being modified) and used the completion of the for loop itself as a means of determining whether or not the number is acceptable. +1 for edit and clean code